# Firebase Cloud Messaging - как добавлять ссылки в оповещения?

Tags: android

Может кто-то сможет объяснить мне, как сделать push-оповещения с ссылками, которые бы открывали определенный раздел приложения?

На данный момент я имею :

1. приложение для сайта, сделанное через webview
2. push - оповещения, без правильный обработки ссылок, т.е при нажатии просто запускается главная моего приложения

На сайте **FireBase** есть пункт вставки данных в сообщение , а вот как в приложении его обрабатывать, не  пойму :(
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо.

Comment: что у вас именно не получается, и покажите код где вы обрабатываете bundle вашего push уведомления, там и нужно колдовать.